# How to get ordinal value for Microsoft WIndowsCE `SetEvent` function?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-ce

I am trying to make a Shim application which could inform me about when and where `SetEvent` function is called.To make this shim application i need to register my custom API to Ordinal number of `Setevent` function in shim.def.

Below is example of my def file where left is API name and right is standard ordinal value from Microsoft

```
APIHook_CeSetUserNotification               @473
APIHook_CeSetUserNotificationEx             @1352
APIHook_CreateProcessW                      @493
APIHook_SetTimeZoneInformation              @28
QueryShimInfo                               @7
APIHook_SetEventData                        @1528
```

Please let me know how can i get ordinal value for [SetEvent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Open *kernel32.dll* with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It displays the ordinal of exports alongside the symbol name.

Comment: @IInspectable thnaks for comment but could you please suggest something similar for Windows CE6?

Comment: Use coredll.dll instead, copy it from the device to your dev machine.

Comment: @HansPassant i tried to dump coredll.dll but it mentions about `SetEventData` function which is different from what i used in my code. I am using `SetEvent`

Comment: I am 99% sure SetEvent is there as well, keep looking.

Comment: i have checked it properly but there is no SetEvent. Perhaps there is some other dll what is responsible for this.

Comment: The function you linked to is not in CE, it's the desktop link that you gave us. Please don't make us read the comments to understand what you are trying to do. Please fix the question.

Comment: Ordinals numbers are not part of the API contract. They can and do change from version to version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows CE SetEvent is defined like this in the header:

```
_inline BOOL SetEvent(HANDLE h) {
    return EventModify(h,EVENT_SET);
}
```

So you need to hook EventModify which is in coredll.dll

You'll find the ordinal using:

```
dumpbin  /EXPORTS  coredll.dll
```

Alternatively you can also find the ordinal in the coredll.def file in your CE sdk:

```
EventModify=xxx_EventModify @494
```

Comment: Read the comments, he's trying to do this for Windows CE.

Comment: @HansPassant I saw that too late. OP should have been more specific. I've edited my answer to be CE specific.